# Getting AccessDeniedException when running embedded cassandra with Azul jdk 11

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to run embedded Cassandra using cassandra-unit library in **Azul JDK 11** with Gradle project and getting following AccessDenindException. I've checked the permissions of the `build` folder it is not readonly and there are some files already. Don't have anything else in the project which might causing the issue.

```
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: build\embeddedCassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1642719269564.log
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:143)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.discard(CommitLogSegment.java:409)
```

**Java class**

```java
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
```

**build.gradle**

```
testCompile 'org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit:4.3.1.0'
testCompile 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.13.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any magic that happens here since Cassandra is simply using the Java IO utilities so this is a low-level filesystem issue.

One of the things to check for is whether the existing commit logs in the directory are owned by a different user that the Cassandra process does not have access to. For example, `CommitLog-6-1642719269564.log` is owned by `root` but the C* process is running with `cassandra`. If so, you will need to change the file ownership. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** Java 11 is only supported from Cassandra 4.x. Earlier versions of Cassandra only work with Java 8.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that permissions error from the outside? Or the only thing to do is to observe an error and wait for fix?

Comment: @yu.pitomets it might not be a permission issue after all. Java 11 is only supported for Cassandra 4.x+ and won't work with earlier versions of Cassandra. Commit log version `-6-` indicates you're running Cassandra 3.x. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check the test dependency tree for version downgrades with `gradle dependencies`. My Apache Cassandra and Java Native Access libs were getting downgraded by Spring Boot 2.2. Fixing the JNA version took care of the AccessDeniedException error in Windows.

Additionally, CassandraUnit uses a JDK-internal Cleaner class that is restricted in Java 11. You can add a JVM arg in the test task(s) to make it available again.

The relevant build.gradle snippets are shown below.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit:4.3.1.0'
    testImplementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.11.3'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:4.0.8' // override 3.x from spring-data-cassandra
    testImplementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0'              // override 4.5 from spring-boot-dependencies
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    // allow cassandraunit to use jdk11 internal Cleaner
    jvmArgs '--add-exports', 'java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED'
}
```